# Calculating slope of each point in Dataframe

Tags: r

I've a calculated the K dist neighbours in a dataset. Now, I want to calculate the slope of each point.
my data frame looks like this

```
X1           X2         X3           X4
==========================================================
0.1000000   0.1414214   0.1414214   0.1414214
----------------------------------------------------------
0.1414214   0.1414214   0.1414214   0.1732051
----------------------------------------------------------
0.1414214   0.2449490   0.2645751   0.2645751
----------------------------------------------------------
0.1414214   0.1732051   0.2236068   0.2449490
----------------------------------------------------------
0.1414214   0.1414214   0.1732051   0.1732051
----------------------------------------------------------
0.3316625   0.3464102   0.3605551   0.3741657
----------------------------------------------------------
0.2236068   0.2645751   0.3000000   0.3162278
----------------------------------------------------------
0.1000000   0.1414214   0.1732051   0.2000000
----------------------------------------------------------
0.1414214   0.3000000   0.3162278   0.3464102
----------------------------------------------------------
0.1000000   0.1732051   0.1732051   0.1732051
----------------------------------------------------------


    structure(list(X1 = c(0.1, 0.141421356237309, 0.141421356237309, 
    0.14142135623731, 0.346410161513775), X2 = c(0.14142135623731, 
    0.33166247903554, 0.1, 0.244948974278318, 0.1), X3 = c(0.14142135623731, 
    0.223606797749979, 0.100000000000001, 0.412310562561766, 0.33166247903554
    ), X4 = c(0.14142135623731, 0.0999999999999996, 0.223606797749979, 
    0.360555127546399, 0.141421356237309)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", 
    "X3", "X4"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to calculate slope by using difference function.

```r
data <- data.frame(data)
slope  <-  function(x){
    if(all(is.na(x)))

        return(NA)
    else
        return(coef(lm(I(1:4)~x))[2])
}


df$slope1  <- apply(data(,c("X1","X2","X3","X4")),1,slope)
```

I am expecting slope for each row so that I can find standard deviation and mean of those values

Comment: Please post a sample of your data with `dput`. Use `dput(head(df,n))`.

Comment: as.vector(apply(data[,c("X1","X2","X3","X4")],1,slope))

Comment: @mr.joshuagordon there's an error

Error in df$slope1 <- as.vector(apply(data[, c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4")], : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: @NelsonGon Here is output


structure(list(X1 = c(0.1, 0.14142135623731, 0.14142135623731, 
0.14142135623731, 0.141421356237309), X2 = c(0.141421356237309, 
0.14142135623731, 0.244948974278318, 0.173205080756888, 0.141421356237309
), X3 = c(0.14142135623731, 0.14142135623731, 0.264575131106459, 
0.223606797749979, 0.173205080756888), X4 = c(0.14142135623731, 
0.173205080756888, 0.264575131106459, 0.244948974278318, 0.173205080756888
)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: PLease add it to your question.

Comment: This works for me: `apply(df,1, function(x) coef(lm(I(1:4)~x)) )`? Why do you use `return` anyways?

Comment: @NelsonGon one more thing. how to calculate the Standard Deviation of slopes??

Comment: `sd(apply(df,1, function(x) coef(lm(I(1:4)~x)) )[2,])` ? Or 1 for 2.

Comment: @NelsonGon there's an error

Error in model.frame.default(formula = I(1:4) ~ x, drop.unused.levels = TRUE): variable lengths differ (found for 'x')

Comment: I have no idea how many columns your actual data has.

Comment: I only  need SD of the slopes we just calculated above using apply function.